# Change author using Safecracker

Tags: safecracker

I'm looking at a way to change the author of a channel entry through a Safecracker form, in same style as used in the CP with a drop down select.

From what I can see it needs some sort of query, I've tried all sorts with variables member_id and author_id within tag pairs, without any results writing back to db.

Anyone done this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had this issue. It'd be nice if this functionality was available via a native tag or a third party plugin, but in the meantime, I used the following code with the Query module:

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT member_id, screen_name, group_id FROM exp_members ORDER BY group_id DESC, screen_name ASC;"}
  <option value="{member_id}" {if "{member_id}" == "{author_id}"}selected="selected"{/if}>{screen_name}</option>
{/exp:query}
```

The above code worked fine for me in EE 2.5.5. If you get T_STRING errors (which I got in certain situations for certain members in EE 2.5.0 when using the above), then try changing the conditional that picks the current author from:

```
{if "{member_id}" == "{author_id}"}selected="selected"{/if}
```

to:

```
{if {member_id} == {author_id}}selected="selected"{/if}
```